# C programming - What am I doing wrong with these functions?

Tags: c, function, max, min, median

This program I've written is supposed to ask for salaries, figure out the min, max value, average, median, and then sort them in decending order and display it. The program runs, but the max, min, avg, and the amount of salaries are completely off. I've been searching, re-reading and just can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Please help!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Function Prototypes */

int get_number_of_salaries (void);

void enter_salaries (int [], int);

void sort (int [], int);

void ending_sort (int [], int); 

float get_median (int [], int);

float average (float []);

int minimum_value (int [], int);

int maximum_value (int[], int);



/* Functions */

int get_number_of_salaries (void)
{
    int number_of_salaries;
do
{
    printf ("Enter the number of salaries to process (2-100): ");
    scanf ("%i", &number_of_salaries);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (number_of_salaries <= 1)
        printf (" I'm sorry, you need to enter more than one salary.\n\n");
    if (number_of_salaries > 100)
        printf (" I'm sorry, you can not enter more than 100 salaries.\n\n");

} while (number_of_salaries <= 1 || number_of_salaries > 100);

return number_of_salaries;

}

void enter_salaries ( int salaries [], int number_of_salaries)

{
int i;


for ( i = 1; i <= number_of_salaries; ++i)
{
    do 
    {
        printf (" Enter salary #%i: ", i);
        scanf ("%i", &salaries[i]);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (salaries[i] <= 0)
            printf (" *** Invalid salary entered. Please re-enter. *** \n");

    } while (salaries[i] <= 0);



} 

printf ("\n");

}

int minimum_value (int salaries [], int number_of_salaries)
{
int minimum, i;

minimum = salaries [0];

for (i = 1; i < number_of_salaries; ++i)
    if (salaries [i] < minimum)
        minimum = salaries [i]; 

return minimum;

}


int maximum_value (int salaries [], int number_of_salaries)
{
int maximum, i;

maximum = salaries [0];

for (i = 1; i < number_of_salaries; ++i)
    if (salaries [i] > maximum)
        maximum = salaries [i];

return maximum;

}

float average ( float a[])
{
int i, number_of_salaries;
float avg, sum = 0.0;
for (i = 0; i < number_of_salaries; ++i)
{
    sum += a[i];
}

avg = (sum/number_of_salaries);

return avg;
 }

 void sort (int salaries [], int number_of_salaries)

 {

int i, j, temp;


    for (i = 0; i < number_of_salaries - 1; ++i)
        for (j = i + 1; j < number_of_salaries; ++j)
        if (salaries [i] > salaries [j])
        {

            temp = salaries[i];
            salaries[i] = salaries[j];
            salaries[j] = temp;
        }



} /* end swap */

float get_median (int salaries[], int number_of_salaries)
{
float temp;
int x, i;

for (x = 0; x < number_of_salaries; ++x)
for (i = x + 1; i < number_of_salaries; ++i)
{
    if (salaries[x] > salaries [i])
    {
        salaries[i] = temp;
        salaries[i] = salaries[x];
        salaries[x] = temp;
    }
}

if (number_of_salaries % 2 == 0)
return (salaries[number_of_salaries / 2] + salaries[number_of_salaries / 2 - 1]) / 2;
else
return salaries[number_of_salaries / 2];
printf (" The median salary is %.1f \n", get_median);

}

void ending_sort (int salaries[], int number_of_salaries)
{
int i, j, temp;



    for (i = 0; i < number_of_salaries - 1; ++i)
        for (j = i + 1; j < number_of_salaries; ++j)
        if (salaries [i] < salaries [j])
        {
            temp = salaries[i];
            salaries[i] = salaries[j];
            salaries[j] = temp;
        }
}


int main (void)
{
/* Variable Declarations */
/*-----------------------*/
int salaries [100];
int number_of_salaries, maximum, minimum, x, i; 
float avg;
int total_salary;
float median;

/* Output Greeting */
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
printf (" Welcome to the Salary Calculator.\n");




number_of_salaries = get_number_of_salaries ();

enter_salaries (salaries, number_of_salaries);

minimum_value (salaries, number_of_salaries);

maximum_value (salaries, number_of_salaries);

printf (" The minimum salary is %i \n", minimum);

printf (" The maximum salary is %i \n", maximum);

printf ("\n"); /* Spacing. */

average (salaries);

printf (" The average salary rounded is %i \n", avg);

sort (salaries, number_of_salaries);

get_median (salaries, number_of_salaries);

median = get_median (salaries, number_of_salaries);

printf (" The median salary is %.1f \n", median);

ending_sort (salaries, number_of_salaries);

printf (" The salaries entered were: \n");
for (x = 1; x < number_of_salaries; ++x)
    printf ("%i", salaries[x]);



printf ("\n");


getchar ();

} /* End Main */
```

Comment: Please be more specific, and perhaps narrow your problem down.  Can  you isolate one of these functions that is producing incorrect output, and show just code demonstrating it?  Please include the expected results and the actual results.  As it's written now, you've just shown a "wall-of-code" and asked for StackOverflow to debug it for you, but good StackOverflow questions will typically involve some debugging ahead of time.  Please narrow down the question.

Comment: You don't assign the returned values of most of your functions (except the median) and then print uninitialized variebles.

Comment: By the way, if `sort()` and `ending_sort()` do exactly the same, you don't need both of them.

Comment: One error is that variables maximum, minimum and avg are uninitialized. Another is that you are storing salaries in array salaries starting from salaries[1] but in minimum_value method you are assigning minimum as salaries[0]

Answer (score 1):

In enter_salaries your for loop looks like this

```
for ( i = 1; i <= number_of_salaries; ++i)
```

The very first value in array will be at index `0` and the last one at index `number_of_salaries - 1`  so change your loop to

```
for ( i = 0; i < number_of_salaries; ++i)
```

Check other functions, they all have same problems. In `average` function you declare `number_of_salaries` in the body of function, and use it without initialization. I guess you wanted to pass `number_of_salaries` the same way you do it in other functions. Also `salaries` became array of floats in average prototype while it initially it is `int`

Answer (score 0):

One error is that variables maximum, minimum and avg are uninitialized. Another is that you are storing salaries in array salaries starting from salaries[1] but in minimum_value method you are assigning minimum as salaries[0]. So in minimum_value you can change :

minimum = salaries [1];

for (i = 2; i < number_of_salaries; ++i)

and similar in other maximum_value method....

Also change your code in main as:

minimum=minimum_value (salaries, number_of_salaries);

maximum=maximum_value (salaries, number_of_salaries);